# Properly Setting up Traefik HTTPS

Tags: traefik

So I have several different domains that would be pointing to my server that is running Docker and Traefik as a reverse proxy.

I want Traefik to convert all HTTP traffic to HTTPS, but is it possible to to have individual SSL certificates (issued by Let's Encrypt) for each domain that is hosted by the server?

If it is possible, how can I properly set this up in the traefik.toml file?

I see this:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "test@traefik.io"
storage = "acme.json"
caServer = "http://172.18.0.1:4000/directory"
entryPoint = "https"

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "local1.com"
  sans = ["test1.local1.com", "test2.local1.com"]
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "local2.com"
  sans = ["test1.local2.com", "test2x.local2.com"]
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "local3.com"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "local4.com"
```

But is it possible to have Traefik send a request to generate a certificate based on what is entered in the traefik.frontend.rule ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, follow the traefik + letsencrypt guide here : https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/docker-and-lets-encrypt/

Traefik can connect to the docker daemon, and automatically check the labels for `traefik.frontend.rule` and generate hosts and SSL certificates from these.